# C++ file reading error

Tags: c++, error-handling, readfile

So my text.txt looks like this:

```
208 84  Sally Goodnow       30:23   52  F   Lancaster
209 344 Scott Grady         30:28   42  M   Clinton
210 191 gail holland        30:36   52  F   worcester
211 43  Karen Hughes        30:45   46  F   Shirley
212 221 Edward m Powers Jr. 30:48   60  M   Clinton
213 173 Lisa Zancewicz      30:49   34  F   Clinton
214 186 Julianne Ryll       30:54   51  F   Clinton
215 245 Briana Gibson       30:54   27  F   Marlborough
```

my code to read the file looks like this:

```
int a;
int b;
string c;
string d;
string e;
string f;
string g;
string h;

string mystr;
int mymin;
int mysec;

int i;


int count=0;
while((infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g)&&getline(infile, h))
```

my code just breaks at line 212, I think it has to do with the name Edward m Powers Jr. (now I really hate this name, every time I look at it, lol). The name uses up my four strings, making h=60  M   Clinton. Is is because string h cannot store integer 60 in it? I don't think that's the reason.

I'm doing the getline(infile, h) because I don't care about the name of town, Lancaster, Clinton are town names.

I tried to skip line 212, I did something like this:

```
string all
while(getline(infile, all)
{
   if(all.at[0]!='2'&&all.at[1]!='1'&&all.at[2]!='2')
   {
      infile>>a>>b>>c>>d>>e>>f>>g;
      getline(infile, h);
```

I'm doing this just to skip line 212, but it did not work. It just breaks at other lines.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like at least half the input parsing questions here on stackoverflow.com have to do with the `>>` operator. I never liked using this operator. It has certain, rigid semantics affecting both input parsing and the input stream's error state, and unless the input matches the same semantics, using the `>>` operator will not work reliably.

And, adding insult to injury, in the real world the input is rarely a match for 100% of `>>`'s idiosyncrasies.

In this case, your problem is that you should not be using the `>>` operator at all. The `>>` operator is for parsing whitespace-delimited strings. You have correctly identified, more or less, where your problem is, now you just need to take one final step, to complete your training as a Jedi, and ditch the `>>` operator completely. You cannot easily use it to parse this kind of input.

Your input looks like a bunch of fixed-width fields. The fields always occupy the same character positions, on each line. That's what it looks to me. The `>>` operator is not meant to be used for parsing such input.

Rather, you should be reading the input one line at a time, using `std::getline`(), then using the `substr()` method to extract each field from its corresponding character positions. Then, for each individual field, trim the trailing whitespace, which is trivial.

P.S. You are not even using the `>>` operator on the right object. You're already using `std::getline()` to read each line of input, but then inexplicably use the `>>` operator on the input stream object anyway. That's wrong. You need to parse the line you have just read, rather than the following input in the file, by constructing a `std::istringstream` based on the line just read, then using the `>>` operator on **that** object. But, as I said, you should not be using the `>>` operator anyway...